# how can I use macro to change a number inside some text

Tags: c, macros

If I have a function `dostuff_1` and another function, `dostuff_2` and N other functions `dostuff_N`, is there a way I can make a macro like `#define DOSTUFF(X) ...` so that `DOSTUFF(5)` gives me `dostuff_5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

`#define DOSTUFF(X) dostuff_##X()`

The preprocessor will [replace](https://ideone.com/zNYQ9y) every existence of `DOSTUFF(X)` in your code to `dostuff_x()`.

On the other hand, consider renaming your methods to something meaningful.